# How to cache downloaded google maps data on an Android activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I have a `MapView` acitivty and it download some maps data from google. How can I cache these data and how can I load them again to use offline?

I need these maps cached to use them when there is no way to download them (neither 3G nor Wifi connection). GPS gets localization, but if there's no map, it is not helpful for user.

Note: Some comment in this post, said that is violation to Google Maps TOS, and it will not be possible to upload to Android Market, but It does not matter because It will not be published, it is only for academic and research purposes.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Technically It is possible, but it is a violation of the google maps TOS, so don't expect to be able to put your application on the market.

Comment: If it is possible. Can you tell me how?